# Jersey returns HTTP Status 405 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, jax-ws

I have a very simple endpoint using Jersey. My URL is static, it doesn't require any request parameters. It looks like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/mydata")
@Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
public String getData()  {
  return "{'name': 'value'}";
}
```

However, whenever I request this URL, I always receive a HTTP Status code of 405 - Method Not Allowed.

The weird thing is, that if I change the `@Path` annotation and define a path variable e.g. `@Path("/chart/{blah}")` it works fine.

Does anyone have an idea why I have to define a path variable to get this to work? I don't need a path variable and it seems silly to add one just to get a 200 response.

Comment: How are you requesting the URL? e.g. - post the actual URL you are trying to use.

Comment: The URL I am using is: http://localhost:8080/mydata

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. It ended up being me stupidly entering an incorrect url-pattern for my jersey SpringServlet. It was `/` instead of `/*`

```xml
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Chart Service</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 6):

Annotate the class instead of the method:

```
@Path("/mydata")
public class MyClass(){

@GET
@Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  
public String getData()  {
  return "{'name': 'value'}";
}

}
```

I don't know why but it also gives me problems the other way

Answer (score 4):

I think it's probably because you specified

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
```

1) Maybe you should try running the following in a terminal

```
curl -i -X GET -H 'Accept:application/json' http://localhost:8080/mydata
```

2) Or try change to

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately both of these still result in a 405 being returned.

Comment: @seedhead sorry, can you try method 1 again? I realized that I copy and pasted the wrong header

Answer (score 4):

another possible source of such problem: be very attentive with all the params and annotations. I was having such problem, when I was calling a method with POST, while it was annotated with `@PUT`

Answer (score -7):

I was suffering the same problem; http://localhost:8080/mypath/myendpoint wasn't working.

Try adding "/rest" to the path, as in http://localhost:8080/rest/mypath/myendpoint